# Did a woman from Gaza give birth to 69 kids before her death?

Tags: pregnancy

According to [Al Arabiya](https://english.alarabiya.net/en/variety/2017/03/01/40-year-old-woman-from-Gaza-gave-birth-to-69-kids-before-her-death.html):

> A 40-year-old Palestinian woman has given birth to 69 kids, her husband was quoted as saying by Gaza Al-An news agency.
>
> The husband confirmed that his wife died on Sunday.
>
> According to global statistics, the deceased mother was the most fertile woman in the world.

Is this story true?

Comment: It isn't clear from the source, do they claim that she birthed them all in one pregnancy?

Comment: @SIMEL I assume it was a lifetime "achievement", but it doesn't say so directly

Comment: Simple math suggests this is improbable.  Assume she first became pregnant at 15 (just to make the math easy).  25 years = 300 months.  Given that a pregnancy lasts 9 months, that's 33 pregnancies.  So virtually all the births would have had to have been twins or triplets, and the woman would have had to become pregnant immediately after giving birth.

Comment: @jamesqf: We should *expect* the most fertile woman in the world to be have had a very unlikely number of multiple births - on the order of 1 in tens of billions.

Comment: The phrase "her husband was quoted as saying" means that someone told the website that the husband said that. Even the website isn't stating that this is a fact, or even that it was definitely claimed.

Comment: @jamesqf: But the official world record number of births by a single woman is 69. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_with_the_most_children#Female_and_monogamous_couples http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/most-prolific-mother-ever

Comment: @KennyLJ no real proof of that either

Comment: @Kenny LJ: Even if that claim was proved, the woman had a much longer time to do it it.

Comment: @KennyLJ That claim is analyzed here: http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20151020-did-one-woman-really-give-birth-to-69-children